# Retrieve a list of Google Drive folders using the API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of all folder titles/ids in a specific Google Drive folder.

What i have found, that almost resembles what i need is the following:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list

From that page i can type in the start folder and i can also add a mimetype to the query string: mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' to return only folders.

The problem is that i only get back a set of ID's. That isn't very practical since i can not display them to the user in a dropdown list. 
Is there any other method to actually get the title of the folders (along with the ID's)?

Something like:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#childReference",
  "id": string,
  "selfLink": string,
  "childLink": string,
  "title": string      <-----
}
```

What is the best way to solve this, do one request for every folder (a lot of folders) each time i need to populate the dropdown list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [files#list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) method with a `in parents` search parameter, like described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters). You can combine that with the `mimeType` option that you mentioned.

It will return a lot of information, you'll probably want to specify the `fields` parameter as well to get only what you need.

Comment: the question is asking about folders and you're answering about files. Doesn't make sense

Comment: @MorDeror a folder is a kind of file, you have to use the `mimeType` filter with the `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` value to get only folders

Comment: How do you get the webViewLink when you retrieve a list of all the folders? I don't seem to be able to get it by setting the fields property to "webViewLink" or "files(webViewLink)"

Comment: @WYS I think it's `items/webViewLink` if you only want the webViewLink or `items(id,webViewLink)` for multiple fields. You can view the syntax by selecting the fields at the API explorer here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list